# Checking a guest customer's email address before order is processed to prevent them from purchasing multiple sample products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hopefully there's a woocommerce veteran familiar with the checkout process that can help me with this. My store offers a sample product at a discounted price, but I want to limit this to a one-time order per customer. I've found a [solution that works for registered users](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/prevent-repeat-purchase-with-woocommerce/) but I was wondering if there's another way to make this work without forcing guests to set up an account before ordering the product.

What I was thinking was if there's a way to check if the customer's billing email address has ordered this particular product at the checkout stage. So they'd fill out the checkout form and click "Proceed" but before the customer is taken through to the payment gateway their email address would be checked for ordering this particular product before, if so, direct them to a "order failed" page rather than through to the payment gateway.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From a fraud standpoint, be mindful of the fact that any Gmail user has a large pool of email addresses available to them by virtue of the period trick, so if you're going to use email address as a key to enforce uniqueness you'll want to standardize them before performing your check.

Answer (score 1):

You have two of ways to achieve this functionality:

1. You can validate email on checkout page itself. Scan for orders with customer/guest's email address and if found with free product, then validate. This way an unnecessary order will not be recorded in the system.

Here is how you can have custom checkout validation.

```
/**
 * Process the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error. This one is only requite for companies
    if ( $_POST['billing_country'] == "NO" )
        if (!$_POST['notes']) 
            $woocommerce->add_error( __('Please add the required information in "Order notes"') );
}
```

2. Alternatively, you can let customer place order and when order is placed, then scan for it if it has already ordered a sample product. And if found, then you can make status of that order as failed. - But this seems a bit illogical.